# Windows 8.1 scheduled task "log on" option with PIN

Tags: windows-8.1, login, task-scheduler

In Windows 8.1, I have selected to log in using a PIN instead of a password. When I create a task in the task scheduler, and set the trigger to "user log on", the trigger fails every time except after a startup - i.e. it won't work after I wake the laptop from sleep modus.

I assume "sign in with a PIN" doesn't qualify as a "log on" for the task scheduler?

If this assumption is correct, how can I schedule a task to run each time I log into Windows with a PIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your computer sleeps you are probably not logging in. Unless you log out every time before you let your PC sleep then you are still logged in and have an active session, you are just unlocking your PC. I am not sure if there is "user unlock" in the task scheduler or not, but that is the event you should be looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that makes sense. Unfortunately there isn't a user unlock trigger in task scheduler... I will dig around, now that I know what to look for - it might be possible to configure a custom trigger for that.

Comment: Correction: such a trigger exists after all - it's called "On workstation unlock". It seems to do the trick. Thanks!